# Extracting the graphs from neo4j output for integration into HTML

Tags: html, neo4j, visualization

I have recently started working with neo4j. I program in python and i use the neo4jrestclient python package to query neo4j. The resulting graphs i am viewing in the neo4j browser. My question is how to extract these graphs just as they appear in the neo4j browser so i can replicate it in another webpage for my project. I am not clear about how to go about this task. I am trying to create network graphs with tweet analysis.

If this is not possible, can anyone suggest any other visualization tool that help create interactive graphs with python. 
Thank you.

Comment: neo4j browser is opensource, you can check https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser to find something that might help you